# Calculate new date values by conditionally adding/subtracting a month

Tags: php, laravel, date, validation

I need to do some checks with some dates in PHP to retrieve data from the database based on what the user chooses, so I'm using this code:

```
if ($request->flagMonth == -1) {
    $query->where(
        ['month', '=', (idate('m')-1)],
        ['year', '>=', (idate('Y')-1)]
    );
}

if ($request->flagMonth == 0) {
    $query->where(
        ['month', '=', idate('m')],
        ['year', '=', idate('Y')]
    );
}

if ($request->flagMonth == 1) {
    $query->where(
        ['month', '=', (idate('m')+1)],
        ['year', '>=', idate('Y')]
    );
}
```

The problem is: when the `idate('m')` is `+1` or `-1`, the result can be `0` or `13` -- which of course are not valid month values.

Is there a different function I can call to operate with dates?

Comment: Why do `-1` and `1` compare the year with `>=`?  I don't understand that business logic.

Comment: Can you explain the `>=` and `=` logic to me?

Comment: This conditional is intended to work with previsions, so the dates we receive tend to be future dates; knowing this, I use this conditionals to check is the database has updated previsions, based on the flag the user chooses.

Comment: If he chooses -1, he wants an older prevision, 0 an actual prevision and +1 a prevision for next month.

Comment: Okay, then it is completely appropriate in my answer to unconditionally use `'='` in the `year` where condition.   I just wanted to be sure.  Thanks.

Comment: So I need to check the year together with the month, in cases when the actual date is for eg: December(Month 12 of 2021), if the user wants the prevision for January(Month 1 of 2022), I check the year, so I don't pull a prevision for January(Month 1) of past years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a datetime object from the first day of the current month, then modify the date using `$request->flagMonth`, then call format()` to access the desired part of the adjusted date.  This precaution of using the first day of the month prevent buggy effects as mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#111989).

No conditions are necessary.

```
$d = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$d->modify("{$request->flagMonth} month");
$query->where(
    ['month', '=', $d->format('n')],
    ['year', '=', $d->format('Y')]
);
```

[Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/DI9NLo)

I don't use Laravel/Carbon, but if you must use a wrapper instead of a native function, I expect that this is a working equivalent because `addMonths()` receives an integer:

```
$d = now()->firstOfMonth()->addMonths($request->flagMonth);
$query->where(
    ['month', '=', (int)$d->month],
    ['year', '=', $d->year]
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just tested it on live code; It is working as well.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, you're using `idate` to get the numerical month, which of course when you subtract or add, it's not going to roll over because it's just a number. The best way to go about it would be to use DateTime, or since you're using Laravel, Carbon, to create a date, do the math, *then* get the numbers you're looking for. Laravel uses `now()` as a shortcut for `Carbon::now()`

```
if ($request->flagMonth == -1) {
    $now = now()->firstOfMonth()->subMonth();
    $query->where(
        ['month', '=', $now->month],
        ['year', '>=', $now->year]
    );
}

else if ($request->flagMonth == 0) {
    $query->where(
        ['month', '=', now()->month],
        ['year', '=', now()->year]
    );
}

else if ($request->flagMonth == 1) {
    $now = now()->firstOfMonth()->addMonth();
    $query->where(
        ['month', '=', $now->month],
        ['year', '>=', $now->year]
    );
}
```

Note that I used `firstOfMonth` when adding or subtracting. This is because when you get to the end of the month, it gets wonky since not all day numbers exist in all months.

Comment: `$request->flagMonth` can never be `-1` and `0` and `1` simultaneously.

Comment: @mickmackusa Very true. I'll edit it for the if/else. I was more focused on the dates.

Comment: Thanks very much for this resolution of the problem, I'll try to apply it on the live code, then I can bring you a good feedback

Comment: Just sent to the application, and it's working as intended.

Comment: I needed to UV this answer because 1. I didn't originally consider using the first of the month and 2. I didn't know about `now()` with Carbon.